# Material UI ghosting issue

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using a `Switch` component from Material UI to expand/collapse elements in a list.  And when seeing the page in Safari on iOS, I'm experiencing a ghosting issue where the switches in the next elements often remain visible after expanding an element.  This is especially bad when using transitions.  But when scrolling the ghost switches disappear and everything looks fine.

Is this a Material UI issue or something else?  Anything I can do as a workaround?

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-switch-ghost-issue-2ie26?file=/src/App.js

[image: Screen capture]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Switch` ripple animation and `Item` animation are flighting for resources to do the animations and Safari seems like it is not able to optimise the animation process.

Therefore, you can add `will-change: transform;` in `Item` css to notify browser there will be a transform event and be ready:

```
const Item = styled.div`
  max-height: ${({ $isSelected }) => ($isSelected ? "20rem" : "2.5rem")};
  will-change: transform;
  transition: max-height 0.1s ease-out;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: gray;
  margin-bottom: 0.2rem;
`;
```

---

The definition of `will-change`:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/will-change

---

Workable codesandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-switch-ghost-issue-forked-fgqqx

Comment: It looks like that did the trick.  Thanks alot!  I didn't know about that CSS property.  Good to know. :-)